# DBX Secure boot keys and windows time boot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, secure-boot, firmware

Last week, i installed ***DBX Firmware*** update through ***ubuntu 23.10*** update, but after that, i still face problem with restart *windows os* which take long time to boot. So, is the dbx have relation to this issue, and how i can downgrade that, i think now is 371 version.

when i tried to installing this update, my system *ubuntu* was completely frozen and when i preform force shutdown that lead my laptop unable to show the factory logo for several seconds then it was start normally